# count of xml array objects

Tags: c#, xml, count, deserialization

```
 <LabelRequest   Test="NO" LabelType="International">
 <MailClass>PriorityMailInternational</MailClass>
 <CustomsInfo>
<ContentsType>Documents</ContentsType>
 <InvoiceNumber>Invoice 678</InvoiceNumber>
<EelPfc>NOEEI 30.37(a)</EelPfc>
<Customs>
  <CustomsItem>
    <Description>Item 1</Description>
    <Value>75</Value>
    <CountryOfOrigin>US</CountryOfOrigin>
  </CustomsItem>
  <CustomsItem>
    <Description>Item 2</Description>
    <Value>25.50</Value>
    <HSTariffNumber>123456</HSTariffNumber>
    <CountryOfOrigin>US</CountryOfOrigin>
  </CustomsItem>
  <CustomsItem>
    <Description>Item 3</Description>
    <Value>27.50</Value>
    <CountryOfOrigin>US</CountryOfOrigin>
  </CustomsItem>
  <CustomsItem>
    <Description>Item 4</Description>
    <Value>33.75</Value>
    <CountryOfOrigin>US</CountryOfOrigin>
  </CustomsItem>
</Customs>
 </CustomsInfo>
  <EelPfc>NOEEI 30.37(a)</EelPfc>
  <CostCenter>95747</CostCenter>
  </LabelRequest>
```

I have an Xml like this.i have to deserialize this xml.whats the problem is,customs in CustomsInfo will not generate same array of customsItem  as above xml, as it contains 4 elements of CustomsItem.it can generate either 5 elements or 6 elements.now how can i count 
how many CustomItem elements were generated in customs.

Comment: _How_ are you deserializing it currently? Are you using Linq-to-XML or `XmlSerializer` or something else?

Comment: i am using XmlSerializer

Comment: Can you post your `LabelRequest` class that you're using to perform the serialization/deserialization with? You should be able to use the `XmlSerializer` to handle the array of `CustomsItems` no problem; just requires a particular attribute in the right spot(s).